# CSV Export failing

Tags: csv, ruby-on-rails-4

As a pragmatic approach I am havin a Report model with different report-records. "require 'csv'" is set in the application.rb.

**schema.rb:**

```
create_table "reports", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.date     "start"
 t.date     "end"
 t.string   "brand"
 t.string   "team"
 t.datetime "created_at", null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

The Report model will act as a generic workaround to generate CSV's. In my **report.rb** I've got the following:

```
def self.to_csv
  CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
    csv << ["Order ID", "User ID", "User name" "Sale price"]
    Order.where("created_at between (?) and (?)", @report.start, @report.end).each do |order|
      order.sales.each do |sale|
          csv << [order.id, order.user_id, order.user_name, sale.price]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

`@report.start` and `@report.end` is defined by the record that was created.

This should actually work and it does, when I'm doing it for the index and not show views.

This is the **report controller**:

```
def show
 @report = Report.find(params[:id])
 respond_to do |format|
   format.html
   format.csv { send_data @report.to_csv, filename: "report-#{Date.today}.csv"}
 end
end
```

and this is in my **views**:

```
<%= link_to report_path(@report, format: "csv"), class: "btn btn-default" do %> #report_path(params[:id], format: "csv") doesn't work either
 Export
<% end %>
```

All I get is:

> NoMethodError in ReportsController#show
>
> > undefined method `to_csv' for #Report:0x007fc86baa2360

and this line from my controller get's highlighted:

> ```
>   format.csv { send_data @report.to_csv, filename: "report-#{Date.today}.csv"}
> ```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Switched to ".as_csv", instead of ".to_csv". In my report.rb Model I switched to `def as_csv ... end` and use `self.start`, `self.end`, ... and so on instead of `@report.start`, ...

In my views I've passed over the report id and the format to the controller:

`<%= link_to report_path(@report.id, format: "csv") do %> ... <% end %>`

Hope that helps someone in the future!